# How to combine separate matrix of x, y and z?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have three separate matrix of x,y,z; all having size of 261*602, I want to combine them into a single matrix so that I can make a 3D plot from it, for example:

| x<sub>11</sub> | x<sub>12</sub> | x<sub>13</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x<sub>21</sub> | x<sub>22</sub> | x<sub>23</sub> |
| x<sub>31</sub> | x<sub>32</sub> | x<sub>33</sub> |

| y<sub>11</sub> | y<sub>12</sub> | y<sub>13</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| y<sub>21</sub> | y<sub>22</sub> | y<sub>23</sub> |
| y<sub>31</sub> | y<sub>32</sub> | y<sub>33</sub> |

| z<sub>11</sub> | z<sub>12</sub> | z<sub>13</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| z<sub>21</sub> | z<sub>22</sub> | z<sub>23</sub> |
| z<sub>31</sub> | z<sub>32</sub> | z<sub>33</sub> |

combine into:

| x<sub>11</sub>,y<sub>11</sub>,z<sub>11</sub> | x<sub>12</sub>,y<sub>12</sub>,z<sub>12</sub> | x<sub>13</sub>,y<sub>13</sub>,z<sub>13</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x<sub>21</sub>,y<sub>21</sub>,z<sub>21</sub> | x<sub>22</sub>, y<sub>22</sub>,z<sub>22</sub> | x<sub>23</sub>,y<sub>23</sub>,z<sub>23</sub> |
| x<sub>31</sub>,y<sub>31</sub>,z<sub>31</sub> | x<sub>32</sub>,y<sub>32</sub>,z<sub>32</sub> | x<sub>33</sub>,y<sub>33</sub>,z<sub>33</sub> |

Is there any simple way to do that? I have tried it on Origin Lab but it doesn't work.

Comment: To be clear, the value in each element of the result is the *product of* the corresponding original elements? "Matrix multiplication" is a completely different operation; what you describe is *elementwise* multiplication of matrices.

Comment: @AlexB this isn't a debugging question; there isn't a problem with code to reproduce. To be clear, [many such questions are indeed on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Honestly, the site would be better off *without* most of the debugging questions it gets.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was trying to plot a 3D graph from the data, matrix multiplication was not my intention, sorry that i didnt state the question clearly

Comment: Ah. The context of the problem isn't important, unless there's a reason for it to impact on how to solve the problem. The matrix data is the matrix data. That said, we need to understand what data you have, and what data you want. If you are actually using Numpy, then show some setup that creates the appropriate Numpy arrays. As for the desired output, you should make sure you understand *exactly* what you need, *according to how you will use it*. That's where the "plot a 3d graph" becomes relevant: *according to the plotting tool's documentation*, what should the result be?

Comment: For example, do you want a 3-dimensional array, where the last dimension represents x/y/z components in order? Do you want an array that stores an ordinary Python tuple (or something else similar) in each element? (Numpy can do this, but it's not really what it's designed for.) Or exactly what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to do element-wise multiplication, along with other common linear algebra operations.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> c = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> a * b * c
array([[  0,   1,   8],
       [ 27,  64, 125],
       [216, 343, 512]])
```

Comment: thanks for replying, actually, I was trying to plot a 3D graph from the data, sorry that I didn't stating the question clearly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform element-wise multiplication of several arrays, you can take advantage of the [`reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) version of [`numpy.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html):

```
lst = [a, b, c]
out = np.multiply.reduce(lst)
```

example output:

```
array([[  0,   6,  24],
       [ 60, 120, 210],
       [336, 504, 720]])
```

used input:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
b = a+1
c = a+2
```